# What exactly goes wrong with $f_!$ outside of locally compact spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of ringed spaces. We define a functor $f_!:\mathcal{O}_X\mathsf{-Mod}\to\mathcal{O}_Y\mathsf{-Mod}$ as
$$\Gamma(U,f_!\mathscr{F}):=\{s\in \Gamma(f^{-1}(U),\mathscr{F})\:|\: f|_{\operatorname{supp}s}:\operatorname{supp}s\to U\text{ is proper}\},$$
where we say that a continuous morphism (between general topological spaces) is proper if it is universally closed.

Defined in this way, the *proper direct image* only seems to be used for locally compact spaces, where we have all the formalism of Verdier duality. In SGA4, P. Deligne says that, for schemes, the derived functors of $f_!$ are pathological. (Section XVII.3.1.) This is possibly why in étale cohomology and for $\mathcal{D}$-modules (possibly in other scenarios) we use other definitions for $f_!$. Moreover, this should be the reason why when studying Grothendieck duality we search for an adjoint of $\mathsf{R}f_*$, instead of $\mathsf{R}f_!$.

**What exactly goes wrong with $f_!$ and its derived functors when the ringed spaces in question are not locally compact?**

Comment: You may find some ideas about this by looking in Chapter 2.5 in the book "Sheaves on Manifolds" by Kashiwara and Schapira.

Comment: @VivekShende I did, in fact, read it. The chapter begins with the definition of $f_!$ without any supposition on the spaces and then the authors say that "Until the end of this section, all spaces will again be assumed to be locally compact spaces." This supposition is used in the proof of the proper base change theorem, but I don't see why the same result can't be true in other categories of ringed spaces. (Since fibered products are different in other categories.)

Comment: Consider their Proposition 2.5.1, in which they *do not* assume local compactness.  It is morally a special case of proper base change, e.g. imagine Z and neighborhoods of Z are compact; push forward along a distance function to Z.  As they write, it may not be an isomorphism unless also the ambient space is Hausdorff; if you want proper base change in some other category this is one thing you have to correct.

Comment: What I mean is that a fiber product of schemes (for example) does not coincide with the fiber product of the underlying topological spaces. Also, I see the tag 09V5 on the Stacks Project as morally a special case of proper base change, and it holds for arbitrary proper separated morphisms on ringed spaces.

Comment: A very practical problem that I see with the functor $f_!$ when dealing with schemes is that it doesn't preserve quasi-coherence (I think). But I wonder if there are other reasons and, in particular, what's the matter with $\mathsf{R}f_!$ that Deligne was hinting.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you study the lower shriek of module sheaves? In the topological / étale case, one considers abelian sheaves. There is a version of lower shriek of "quasi-coherent sheaves", but it is a very recent work: Lecture XI of [Lectures on Condensed Mathematics](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf).

Comment: At the level of derived categories, we know what we want $f_!$ to be when $f$ is either proper or an open immersion, which forces the definition for compactifiable morphisms. Now in the proper case we have a right derived functor, and in the open immersion case we have a left derived functor, so we shouldn't expect the composite to be a derived functor in general. For nice enough topological spaces it turns out to still be the right derived functor of underived $f_!$, but this uses partitions of unity and does not work for schemes: see SGA4 XVII Contre-exemple 6.1.6.

Comment: In short, the issue for schemes is that $R(p_*\circ j_!)\neq R(p_*)\circ j_!$, and it's the right-hand side we're interested in.

Comment: @Z.M Well... Verdier duality holds just as well for module sheaves. (I'm not sure about the étale case though.) I indeed looked at this lecture and Dustin Clausen's masterclass and this seems very interesting. Do you happen to know if the $f_!$ constructed using condensed mathematics coincides with the one I've defined for nonproper $f$? (Perhaps it is not the derived functor of anything?)

Comment: @MarcHoyois What confuses me is that the definition of $f_!$ is SGA4 is the one for the étale topology and it doesn't coincide with the one I've written in the post.

Comment: Could you please give a reference of the Verdier duality for ringed spaces (or topoi)? On the other hand, I don't see any obvious way to relate the solid lower shriek in Clausen-Scholze to the classical one when the map is not proper, since in this case the solid lower shriek is in general not discrete, so at least, it does not "coincide" with the classical one in the naive sense.

Comment: Dear @Z.M, in his article Resolutions of Unbounded Complexes, N. Spaltenstein proves a version of it (supposing some extra condition). In https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400948/verdier-duality-under-more-general-conditions, I proposed a possible proof of it without this condition but I'm not entirely sure if it's correct.

Comment: It is a property of the map $f$ which is needed, not a property of the spaces. Reasonably $f$ must be both separated and locally proper. Any mapping between locally compact Hausdorff spaces has these properties.

Comment: In the setting of étale constructible sheaves, Laszlo-Olsson define functors $Rf_!$ and $f^!$ for any finite type morphism between algebraic stacks locally of finite type. No separation hypotheses are needed.